# Creating a view that span 2 rows react native

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, react-native, view

I want to create 5 views like this in react native.

Check image

[image: 1]

There are 4 views on the right side and one big view on left

Comment: look into css grid

Comment: Does react native support css grid?
if so, can you please link any article for that?

Comment: React native does not support grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is expo snack with solution, just style your borders to not be double :
https://snack.expo.dev/kto6IOXR6

Comment: I tried but lack reputation for that :|

Comment: Tnx for trying :D